# Virtual Joystick moving sprite while changing animations

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm working on a project where I'll have a virtual joystick on the screen which moves a character around the board. I found a few good examples and the one I'm using currently is located @ https://github.com/Ishawn-Gullapalli/SpritekitJoystick/tree/master/SpritekitJoystick

While the player is moved around just like I want, I'm unable to figure out how by using this method I can change the player animation based on the direction he's going. I'm able to determine direction but my usual methods of invoking a SKAction doesn't animate the player, it just moves him to the new location while pausing the idle animation. I'm moving my player in the update statement like below and am looking for tips on how to change animations appropriately.

I'm including my update statement below. I've also tried to pass in a CGPoint value with the same effect. Thanks in advance for looking.

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    if joystick.joyStickTouched == true {

        mainHero.position.x += joystick.moveRight(speed: movementSpeed)

        // Example of me trying to animate my player
        if joystick.moveRight(speed: movementSpeed) > 0 {
            walkRight()
        }

        mainHero.position.x -= joystick.moveLeft(speed: movementSpeed)
        mainHero.position.y += joystick.moveUp(speed: movementSpeed)
        mainHero.position.y -= joystick.moveDown(speed: movementSpeed)
        joystick.update(currentTime)

    }

}


func walkRight() {
    mainHero.isPaused = false
    let idleAnimation = SKAction(named: "MainWalkRight")!
    let rightGroup = SKAction.group([idleAnimation])
    mainHero.run(rightGroup, withKey: "Right")
}
```

Comment: what version of iOS are you using? iOS 11 now creates objects with a paused state. You can try to ensure that the hero isn't paused by adding mainHero.isPaused = false at the beginning of your walk func

Comment: Thank you Ron, that's good to know I was unaware of that change. I believe I'm closer now... I'm still paused while holding down the joystick while my character moves but after I left go the player does 1 frame of walking animation. I'm running IOS 11.2 and have updated my code above with the mainHero.isPaused = false.

Comment: I'm assuming that your action is created in the Scene Editor inside an SKS file. Thus why you are using action named. Have you confirmed that you have the action set to repeat forever? Also you don't need to put idleAnimation in a group unless you have other actions that aren't relevant here

Comment: Hi @Ron Myschuk, you nailed it I'd forgot to repeat my walking animation. Thanks for the tips, silly mistake on my part!

Comment: You are going to encounter another problem where Left and Right could be animating at the same time.  I would recommend sharing the same key in all directions so that you do not have 2 or more different actions running